# What brand of record player was used in "Oblivion"?

Tags: movie, oblivion

This picture shows the record player owned by Jack in the movie *Oblivion*.  What brand was it?

[image: picture of old record player in movie tom list]

Comment: It looks like a very ordinary turntable from around 1970.  If you look closely at the lower left, you can see that the brand name actually appears to have been scraped off.

Answer (score 7):

This looks it's a Panasonic RS-257S as you can see in this [Google search](https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1GCEU_enCA889CA891&source=univ&tbm=isch&q=panasonic+rs-257s&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjnobvngorqAhXJX80KHRamDSQQsAR6BAgKEAE&biw=1372&bih=1023).

[image: Panasonic RS-257S AM/FM/FM Stereo/Cassette/Phono]

If you compare this image to the posted image you can see that the "IC" of "PANASONIC" isn't entirely scraped off.